# Insert Multiple Items Into DynamoDB Using Promise.All

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to insert multiple items into a DynamoDB table using `Promise.all()` by reusing a function that inserts a single item and returns a promise.  The problem I'm having is the array of returned data objects is empty.  That data object is returned correctly when I insert a single item.

I based my implementation on this [AWS Post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/).

My implementation is below:

```
function addMessage(message) {
  const timestamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Item: {
      esn: message.esn,
      utcMsgTimestamp: parseInt(message.utcMsgTimestamp),
      payload: message.payload,
      createdAt: timestamp
    }
  };

  console.log(params);

  return dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
}

function addMessages(messages) {
  // Make all of the addMessage calls immediately, this will return a rejected promise if any fail
  return Promise.all(
    messages.map(message => {
      return addMessage(message);
    })
  );
}
```

My Jest unit test case is here:

```
it.only("add multiple messages", () => {
    const dynamodb = require("../dynamodb");

    expect.assertions(0);

    const messages = [
      {
        esn: "0-700001",
        utcMsgTimestamp: "1034268516",
        payload: "0xC0560D72DA4AB2445A"
      },
      {
        esn: "0-99991",
        utcMsgTimestamp: "1034268521",
        payload: "0xA14AA1DBDB818F9759"
      }
    ];

    return dynamodb.addMessages(messages).then(dataArray => {
      dataArray.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
      });

      // expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your test of a single item call to putItem returns data? Did you request ReturnValues?

Comment: @jarmod, yes I checked the return from a single item call to putItem and it does return data.  I'm not familiar with ReturnValues is this an option that should be set in params?